# Is there any alternative to buttons like in kde for ubuntu unity?

Tags: unity, 16.04, titlebar

i want something like keep above double upward arrow on my windows titles in unity. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: i am so lazy to right click and again click on always on top... i want that to happen by single click with such keep above button

Comment: There are keyboard shortcut for Always On Top function